# CAS Redirect Loop

Tags: java, tomcat, single-sign-on, cas

I am trying to get the CAS setup up and running and I am pretty new to this.

I am following through the standard steps similar to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMP7WXnlSZo).

- I have created keystore file
- Created a certificate
- Imported it successfully and add to cacerts file
- I have made the necessary changes in the server.xml of tomcat

After all these steps, I started the tomcat, placed the war in the webapp and to test, I tried to access http://localhost:8080/cas/login and https://localhost:8443/cas/login and it is throwing and Redirect loop error.

I have no clue what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated!.

[image]

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this often happens when whatever is handling your url security (an interceptor of sorts) thinks that your login URL itself requires authentication. Thus, you get stuck in an infinite redirect loop. As such, make sure that `/cas/login` does not require authentication to reach in your application

Comment: i have not used cas for my application yet... I have just deployed the cas server in the tomcat and tried to access the default /cas/login page available. So I am wondering what I did wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was nothing to do with my configuration.

I watched several videos and understood that my configuration do not have any problems. The problem is with the 4.0.0 release. I do not know if any one else faced the same problem.

**My Solution:** I took latest source (4.0.2) and built the war using maven and deployed. It worked perfectly.